# Run .exe application in background with c# code

Tags: c#, background-process

I want write an app that opens proxifier(portable edition) in background(without gui).
I tried this code but it just opens proxifier in normal mode(it shows gui again):

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("pfier.exe") 
{
 CreateNoWindow = true,
 UseShellExecute = false,
 WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
 RedirectStandardOutput = true 
}; 

Process pfier = new Process();
pfier.StartInfo = info;
pfier.Start();
```

I'm new at c# and I don't know it's possible or not. Thanks for help.

Comment: @jdweng That won't change the behavior of a process that's run like this.

Comment: @Servy : You are wrong.  Any code placed i a background worker and run in async mode will run in background mode.

Comment: @jdweng You are wrong.  How a process runs has nothing to do with what threads the process is started in.  Plenty of processes don't even *have* any kind of "background mode", saying that creating the process from a background threads always runs it in "background mode" doesn't even make any sense.  If a process *has* any sort of non-UI mode (if that's not its standard means of execution), it needs to be indicated in some way that it can notice, usually a command line argument, although possibly something else like a config file or standard input or any number of other options.

Comment: Try setting ProcessStartInfo.Arguments property to the command line parameters that will start it in silent mode.

Comment: @Servy : What is the difference between Background Mode and Async?

Comment: @jdweng They're your terms, I was quoting you.  The OP's code is already asynchronous, they're asking how to run this program without a UI.  None of this has anything to do with running CPU bound code in a different thread while updating a UI thread with the results, which is what a Background Worker is there for.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng . I tried that but nothing changed. Servy was right.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. But I don't have any tutorials that how can run it in background with arguments and for that I wanted to see can I run it from code in background or not.

Comment: @PokerFaCe, I am not familiar with that proxy app.  I would recommend reading the documentation for [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/docs/win-v3/profiles.htm).  If there is a way to launch it as an app silently, it should be documented.  Depending on your requirements, you could consider setting it up as a Windows Service and start/stop the service from your code.

Comment: Thank @Adam , I use a portable version of proxifier for my app and when I talked with poxifier's support, they said there is no way to run portable version in background mode! But i see an application who uses this portable version in it's background. so I think there should be a way to run proxifier in background from code

Comment: @PokerFaCe They may have it installed as a Windows Service and are interacting with the service from their app, this may be an option for you.